# UDP traffic through SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, tunnel, udp

The title pretty much sums it up.  I would like to send UDP traffic through a SSH tunnel.  Specifically, I need to be able to send UDP packets through the tunnel and have the server be able to send them back to me on the other side.  I know how to do it for TCP connections. Is this it possible with UDP?

Comment: Can you post how to do it for TCP connections?

Comment: @GabrielStaples the feature mentioned is called "port forwarding". You can simply search for "ssh port forwarding". Here's one of search results - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding . I hope you'll find what you need.

Comment: @VictorYarema, thanks. I also experimented and wrote a basic UDP port forwarding program in Python: [socket_udp_port_forwarding.py](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/socket_udp_port_forwarding.py) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo. I'm sure I could convert it from UDP to TCP too.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[This small guide](http://www.qcnetwork.com/vince/doc/divers/udp_over_ssh_tunnel.html) tells you how to send UDP traffic via SSH using tools that come standard (ssh,nc,mkfifo) with most UNIX-like operating systems.

## Performing UDP tunneling through an SSH connection

#### Step by step

### Open a TCP forward port with your SSH connection

On your local machine (local), connect to the distant machine (server) by SSH, with the additional -L option so that SSH will do TCP port-forwarding:

```
local# ssh -L 6667:localhost:6667 server.foo.com
```

This will allow TCP connections on the port number 6667 of your local machine to be forwarded to the port number 6667 on server.foo.com through the secure channel.

### Setup the TCP to UDP forward on the server

On the server, we open a listener on the TCP port 6667 which will forward data to UDP port 53 of a specified IP. If you want to do DNS forwarding like me, you can take the first nameserver's IP you will find in /etc/resolv.conf.

But first, we need to create a fifo. The fifo is necessary to have two-way communications between the two channels. A simple shell pipe would only communicate left process' standard output to right process' standard input.

```
server# mkfifo /tmp/fifo
server# nc -l -p 6667 < /tmp/fifo | nc -u 192.168.1.1 53 > /tmp/fifo
```

This will allow TCP traffic on server's port 6667 to be forwarded to UDP traffic on 192.168.1.1's port 53, and responses to come back.

### Setup the UDP to TCP forward on your machine

Now, we need to do the opposite of what was done above on the local machine. You need priviledged access to bind the UDP port 53.

```
local# mkfifo /tmp/fifo
local# sudo nc -l -u -p 53 < /tmp/fifo | nc localhost 6667 > /tmp/fifo
```

This will allow UDP traffic on local machine's port 53 to be forwarded to TCP traffic on local machine's port 6667.
Enjoy your local DNS server :)

As you've probably guessed, when a DNS query will be performed on the local machine, e.g. on local UDP port 53, it will be forwarded to local TCP port 6667, then to server's TCP port 6667, then to server's DNS server, UDP port 53 of 192.168.1.1. To enjoy DNS services on your local machine, put the following line as first nameserver in your /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This solution is not safe. TCP streams are not guaranteed to preserve message boundaries, so a single UDP datagram may be split in parts, breaking any protocol.

Comment: It could also be nice to use port 1153 instead of 6667 (from man SSH example), which is used by IRC.

Comment: @JuhoÖstman Thanks for pointing out this pitfall. Being aware of the problem... have you run accros a solution? would small enough messages be a way to make it likely to work?

Comment: The solution would be to prepend a length to each packet before they are sent through the TCP stream, and reconstruct the original packets from that. It would easy to write a C script to do that, but I am not sure if a readily-available solution exists. In practice, the TCP usually seems to preserve message boundaries in this case, but strange failures can occur at any time.

Comment: I faced another problem with this: the pipe and fifo are buffered so frame boundaries are lost. So many UDP frames can be concatenated into one TCP frame.

Comment: Mac OS Sierra's `nc` complains about this `sudo nc -l -u -p 53 </tmp/dnsfifo | nc localhost 6866 > /tmp/dnsfifo` saying "nc: missing port with option -l" but oddly each command without the pipe works fine, so it's pretty odd. Of course they don't actually function if they don't pipe to each other so...

Comment: I had to install the homebrew netcat `brew install netcat` to get around the MacOS whack-a-do problem. But then I could not get OpenVPN traffic through, Maybe the boundary issue?

Answer (score 51):

This [example](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html) (I think John's answer points the the same thing at a different place), describes how to access another machine's UDP/DNS services over an TCP/SSH connection.

> We will forward local UDP/53 traffic to TCP, then TCP traffic with the port-forwarding mechanism of SSH to the other machine, then TCP to UDP/53 on the other end.
>   Typically, you can do it with openvpn.
>   But here, we'll do it with simpler tools, only openssh and netcat.

At the end of that page, is another comment with a reference to '[`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)',
The same UDP/DNS access is made with,

> Server side: `socat tcp4-listen:5353,reuseaddr,fork UDP:nameserver:53`
>   Client side: `socat udp4-listen:53,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:5353`

Refer [socat examples](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES) for more.

Comment: This one seems much more useful for me than the accepted answer.  I needed a unidirectional redirection of video stream (TS/UDP)...  `ssh orig_strm_src socat udp4-listen:4003,reuseaddr,fork STDOUT| socat STDIN udp-sendto:localhost:4003`

Comment: FWIW, I've written a more [detailed guide on my home page](http://www.morch.com/2011/07/05/forwarding-snmp-ports-over-ssh-using-socat/) describing how to set up socat over SSH for UDP forwarding. It uses SNMP as an example.

Answer (score 29):

SSH (at least OpenSSH) has support for simple VPNs. Using the `-w` or `Tunnel` option in the `ssh` client, you can create a `tun` device at both ends, which can be used to forward any kind of IP traffic. (See also `Tunnel` in the manual page of [`ssh_config(5)`](http://man.cx/ssh_config).) Note that this requires OpenSSH (and probably root privileges) at both ends.

Comment: This requires root privileges on remote machine even for UDP tunneling of non-priviledged ports and PermitRootLogin set to not 'no'. Too bad.

Comment: @grawity Thank you for pointing out this option, which even when as pointed out by philpirozhkov the required root login. I wonder if there can be a way to trick it into not needing the root?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: You can precreate the tun/tap devices and make them owned by a specific user, using `ip tuntap add`.

Comment: Hi @grawity. I like your solution but cannot make it work. I precreated the `tun` device as follows: `sudo ip tuntap add mode tun` but when ever using the `-w` option like this: `ssh $Server -w $port` I get `Tunnel device open failed. Could not request tunnel forwarding.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be very helpful to expand this answer from "you can do it" to show how exactly you can do it, which commands to execute

Comment: "**requires ... PermitRootLogin set to not 'no'.**" — @philpirozhkov no it doesn't, you can use "PermitRootLogin without-password" and SSH keys

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov it is badly worded but his statement is logically correct in English. He is saying that it can be set to any other value than 'no'. 'without-password' is different to 'no', so you are not contradicting him.

Answer (score 29):

Or you could simply use **ssf** (which was designed to handle this use case), with a simple command:

---

Client side:

```
#>./ssfc -U 53:192.168.1.1:53 server.foo.com
```

This command redirects local port 53 (dns) to 192.168.1.1 port 53, through a secure tunnel between localhost and server.foo.com.

---

You will need a ssf server (instead of *- or next to -* your ssh server):

```
#>./ssfs
```

By the way, both client and server side of ssf work on Windows / Linux / Mac.
This is a userland application, so you don't need tun/tap or VPN.

To redirect port 53, you will need administrative privileges - regardless of the tool you're using.

For more info, details, use case, or download: https://securesocketfunneling.github.io/ssf/

Comment: At most, it's a shameless plug. Anyway the solution may fit your request. By the way, SSF is OpenSource and non profit.

Comment: @heavyd: If he posted a bunch of hacky scripts, it would be acceptable, but because he made a mature open-source tool, it's not?  It answers the original question perfectly.

Comment: I have to grudgingly admit that this is exactly the tool I've been looking for, even if it was a shameless plug.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs. Specifically forwarding UDP ports.

Comment: I agree with most commenters that it's not spam. But I would not use it for anything that requires security, even if it works perfect. It's rather unknown, which means barely tested, and contains a lot of "own" code. A couple of tiny scripts around well known tools (ssh, socat, netcat, ...) seem safer to me. But that's just my point of view, feel free to disagree.

Comment: seems like `ssfc` would be nice, but Windows Defender identifies the binaries as a Trojan (as obtained from this website in answer above).  I've looked into compiling it myself but can't really be bothered now.

Comment: Would have loved to try it, but it hasn't been maintained in years. I couldn't get it to compile on recent Ubuntu and Manjaro.

Answer (score 18):

I couldn't get `nc` to work for SNMP, because SNMP clients keep choosing a new source UDP port, and several can be active at once.

Instead, I've written a post describing how to do it with `socat` in this [blog post](http://www.morch.com/2011/07/05/forwarding-snmp-ports-over-ssh-using-socat/), using SNMP as an example. Essentially, using two terminals, starting with an overview:

[image: overview]

**Terminal one:**

```
client$ ssh -L 10000:localhost:10000 server
server$ socat -T10 TCP4-LISTEN:10000,fork UDP4:switch:161
```

This creates the SSH forwarding of TCP port 10000 and runs socat on the server. Notice how the switch’s IP address is mentioned in the socat command line as “switch”.

**Terminal two:**

```
client$ sudo socat UDP4-LISTEN:161,fork TCP4:localhost:10000
```

That sets up socat on the client. That should do it.

Comment: this worked for me :)

Comment: Why don't you need a `-R` remote tunnel to tunnel the answer from the UDP server ("switch") back the UDP client ("manager")?

Comment: @bers: socat does that for me

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch alright, thanks. It seems `socat` keeps the existing connection open long enough to tunnel the answer back the same way the request came. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly! And this is the main improvement of `socat` over `nc`. `nc` will do it for one single UDP port combination, which means it will work for SNMP for "some time" until the SNMP manager chooses another source port (which it is free to do for every request). Socat handles that. `nc` doesn't. So with `nc`, SNMP forwarding will work "for a little while" only. And not at all with parallel requests.

Comment: Well if i zabbix server who connects via l2to to network where part of devices is over another. How should i modify you manual ?
I going to use this one "ssh -f -N -L 2035:192.168.2.35:161 user@10.100.10.71" But it seemd to be wrong..

Answer (score 5):

A VPN is a better solution if you have access to an UDP port.

If you only have access to the TCP SSH port, then an SSH tunnel is as good as a VPN, at least for ping and packet backtracking.

Comment: A ssh-only solution won't do it. ssh can only forward tcp traffic. For udp you'll need to tunnel your udp packets over one or more tcp-sockets like they do in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

on ssh server:

```
sudo ip tuntap add dev tun7 mode tun user SSHUSER
sudo ip addr add 192.168.7.1/30 dev tun7
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -i eth0 --dport PUBLIC_PORT -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.7.2:LOCAL_PORT
sudo iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p udp -d 192.168.7.2 --dport LOCAL_PORT -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i tun7 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun7 -j MASQUERADE
# set "PermitTunnel point-to-point" for user SSHUSER in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sshd -t && sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

replace `eth0` with the interface connected to the internet

on ssh client running udp server:

```
sudo ip tuntap add dev tun8 mode tun user LOCALUSER
sudo ip addr add 192.168.7.2/30 dev tun8
ssh -v -w 8:7 SSHUSER@REMOTEHOST
```

you might also need `sudo ip link set tun7 up` on the remote host
and `sudo ip link set tun8 up` on the local host.

inspired by comment [UDP traffic through SSH tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel#comment847864_53149)

Answer (score 0):

An experienced red teamer got this to work and proven by wireshark, but had to change the UDP packets into TCP packets and then forward them into the ssh tunnel and then convert them from TCP packets back into UDP packets to the listener UDP port of the application.

Comment: Please see [How do I write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) -section. I'd suggest [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1680142/edit) the answer to include how exactly the issue was resolved. As it is it's not very helpful, and will likely be flagged for length and quality, and will likely be [deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). This would be OK as a comment, but you will need to collect some [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) before you're allowed to comment.

Comment: @Peregrino69, acctually it is a useful answer. It's very useful to know that UDP packets are not forwardable on their own. Then one can decide what approach to use. For example, I can ask my software that needs tunnel to use TCP and other answers I need to decipher to understand that. I don't need other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sshuttle`](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) to set up a VPN over SSH without the hassle of manually configuring tunnel mode. It supports [UDP](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tproxy.html).

Comment: we need more info