# How can I force netcat to send my input immediately, not just on newlines?

Tags: linux, netcat

How can I force netcat to send my input immediately, not just on newlines? I want to test an HTTP parser manually and check how it behaves when header lines are spread across multiple packets.

Comment: try `socat` as listed in this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/331595/122284)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, which is set by default as the tty `eof` key. When pressed in the middle of a line, it will give to netcat everything that has been input at that point.

The buffering is actually done by the tty layer and not handled by `nc` at all. `stty -icanon && nc ...` would disable the buffering and allow `nc` to see the data as it is entered into the terminal, at which point it will be sent right away. (Note that the `stty` and `nc` commands must be run together, otherwise the shell itself would likely reenable it when displaying its prompt.)

Comment: +1, but is there no option for opening netcat up the way that it does not buffer anything?

Comment: @FinalContest: The buffering is done by the tty layer. `stty -icanon && nc ...` or `stty raw && nc ...` would disable it. [Note that it must be run together, otherwise the shell itself would reenable it when displaying the prompt.]

Comment: @grawity: awesome, the former works fine, but the latter gets stuck... ctrl-c does not work anymore to quit the session, and I cannot get ctrl-z to work on it either. Is that expected? Also, please update your answer so that we can clean the comments up.

Comment: @FinalContest: Yeah, `raw` changes a whole bunch of tty options, one of them being the handling of special "control" keys at tty level. (It is really a "raw" mode, in that it passes _everything_ to the program.) You can use `stty -a -F /dev/pts/XX` from another tty to see the current parameters.

Comment: I am using `stty -icanon -echo && nc ...` otherwise every char I typed in nc get echoed twice