# Tunelling video stream through SSH

Tags: linux, video, ssh, streaming, port-forwarding

I have this problem. There is an udp video stream accessible only on the local network, but I need to access it outside of the network. I have Linux machine (multiple actually) with root access.

There is a small utility that makes the stream accessible on the local machine on port 1234.

```
./ping -h streamserver -p 1234
```

If I run it I can access the stream using vlc or mplayer.

```
mplayer udp://@:1234
vlc udp://@:1234
```

Now, I'm trying to create a port foward from my remote machine and access the port, but it is failing.

```
ssh me@machine -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234
```

Any tips what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See this similar question:http://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that SSH is only capable of port forwarding TCP connections.  The protocol you are interested in is UDP.

This article: http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html shows one method (using DNS as the example) around the problem by encapsulating the UDP in TCP first.

Comment: Hmm. I still can't get it working. I make the ssh tunel: `ssh me@machine -L 6666:127.0.0.1:6666`. Then I run socat on the remote machine: `socat tcp4-listen:6666,reuseaddr,fork UDP:127.0.0.1:1234` and then on local `socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:1234,reuseaddr,fork tcp:127.0.0.1:6666`