# Linux SOCKS5 tunneling not working with udp traffic

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel, udp, socks

I am using the command `ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost` which works perfectly fine for my web browser, but when I try and tunnel a UDP traffic application it doesn't work.

I thought that socks5 should be able to handle UDP traffic, or is there something else that I need to setup?

Comment: perhaps SOCKS is application layer specific. So for example, just as AFAIK, it won't support -any- application layer that uses TCP(just some specific app layer protocols). Perhaps then similarly for UDP.

Comment: Ive used sosck5 proxies before that i Purchased to rout this same application in the same way, so I know that socks 5 is capable of doing it, but i am thinking that it takes some addition setup that i don't know about, server side.

Answer (score 12):

SOCKS 5 supports UDP. OpenSSH [claims to implement SOCKS4 and SOCKS5](https://www.openssh.org/specs.html), but it only implements a *subset* of the SOCKS5 protocol.

You won't find the specifics of what is, or is not supported in the documentation though, look at the source instead:

```
    if (s5_req.version != 0x05 ||
        s5_req.command != SSH_SOCKS5_CONNECT ||
        s5_req.reserved != 0x00) {
            debug2("channel %d: only socks5 connect supported", c->self);
            return -1;
    }
```

(from function `channel_decode_socks5()` in `channels.c`, OpenSSH-6.4p1 from November 8, 2013. **Update** this continues to be the case up to <strike>OpenSSH-7.6p1, October 2017</strike> OpenSSH-8.2p1, February 2020.)

`SSH_SOCKS5_CONNECT` is [command opcode 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928#section-4) which is implicitly a TCP connection. Command opcode 3 is `UDP ASSOCIATE` for UDP proxying (this is what was added to [SOCKS5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS4#SOCKS5), SOCKS4 or 4a do not support UDP).

There are commercial and free (e.g. [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/)) SOCKS5 proxies available that support UDP.

If you do not need *dynamic* UDP port forwarding, you can set up a number (choosing the destinations in advance) of UDP forwardings over an SSH connection using one of these methods: [UDP traffic through SSH tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel)
(I recommend the `socat` approach, I find it to work the best.)