# How to receive and send UDP traffic using a SSH Server with blocked UDP ports?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have an external server which I use to connect to the internet using dynamic port forwarding from my remote desktop . I forward all the connections to my local port 9150 . Therefore I use that socks5 proxy in all my application . But the problem arise in certain application uses UDP for connection and all the UDP ports are blocked in that external server .

Is it even possible to send UDP traffic without using a VPN .

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/678531/598797) looks like that the capability of SOCKS5 to accept UDP is not implemented in the SSH version of SOCKS.

Edit: the above mentioned answer focuses on the programmatic aspect of OpenSSH-6.4p1 from November 8, 2013, especially the function `channel_decode_socks5` from the source code in `channels.c`.

```
  if (s5_req.version != 0x05 ||
        s5_req.command != SSH_SOCKS5_CONNECT ||
        s5_req.reserved != 0x00) {
            debug2("channel %d: only socks5 connect supported", c->self);
            return -1;
    }
```

Having a look at the current source code (because the source code version from above link is older) reveals that also [in the current source code](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/tree/channels.c?id=39c0cecaa188a37a2e134795caa68e03f3ced592#n1219), only socks connect is implemented, UDP is not.

The current source code as of March 2016:

```
if (s5_req.version != 0x05 ||
        s5_req.command != SSH_SOCKS5_CONNECT ||
        s5_req.reserved != 0x00) {
        debug2("channel %d: only socks5 connect supported", c->self);
        return -1;
    }
```

The function `channel_decode_socks5` responsible for allowing "only" TCP and not UDP has not changed since then.  This is the reason why UDP traffic will not pass a socks proxy opened by openSSH.

If you really need UDP, you have several possibilities:

- a) use a VPN connection instead of SSH, e. g. openVPN. The simplest possibility in my eyes.
- b) file a
  feature request with the developers of openSSH. This could take much longer, if it will be implemented at all.
- c) program the
  feature yourself and probably share it with the community. Depending on your C programming skills, this might be even faster than the openVPN solution.