# DNS tunneling through an SSH connection looses connectivity

Tags: linux, dns, ssh-tunnel, netcat

In the Super User question *[UDP traffic through SSH tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel)*, it describes how to tunnel DNS trough a SSH tunnel:

First, on the client side, do this:

```
ssh -N -L 6667:localhost:6667 user@server
```

Then, on the server side do this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
nc -k -l 6667 < /tmp/fifo | nc -u ip_of_dns_server 53 > /tmp/fifo
```

Finally, back on the client side do this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
nc -k -l -u 53 < /tmp/fifo | nc 127.0.0.1 6667 > /tmp/fifo
```

After that I can do a DNS query as expected, *but only for a single request*:

```
client# host m6.fr 127.0.0.1
```

How can I keep the connection alive for more requests?

Comment: Does any `nc` exit after that single successful request? If so, check [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8410538).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: don’t use Netcat, use [Socat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) for experiments. It handles anything better.

The reason it’s not working isn’t about the named pipes (even if it’s an ugly method with other problems lurking around) but a limitation of netcat.

Once Netcat receives an UDP connection, it binds to it. So it’s not listening anymore to the port 53, it’s connected to the port that sent the initial packet, exactly as it'd do with TCP. Each time you’re doing a DNS request, the tool will change port and Netcat will never get the request. So only the first request will work.

When you set up your example, try this command before the first query:

```
netstat -aunp|grep -w 53
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           12316/nc.openbsd
```

Do the (only working) query and try again netstat:

```
# netstat -aunp|grep -w 53
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            127.0.0.1:44335         ESTABLISHED 12316/nc.openbsd
```

As you can see netcat just changed mode: From listening to looping over a connection. Because it’s UDP, Netcat won’t know automatically the “established connection” isn’t there anymore.

I have a proof of concept (that makes it work and shows the problem is related to this UDP mode) but it requires socat in addition to netcat on the client. The goal is to have all requests reach netcat using the same UDP **source** port. Nothing changes on the server side, but I insert socat at the start of the chain (so the last command) to force the source port of the UDP request to Netcat.

First, on the client side, do this:

```
ssh -N -L 6667:localhost:6667 user@server
```

Then, on the server side do this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
nc -k -l 6667 < /tmp/fifo | nc -u ip_of_dns_server 53 > /tmp/fifo
```

Finally, back on the client side do this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
nc -k -l -u 5555 < /tmp/fifo | nc 127.0.0.1 6667 > /tmp/fifo

socat udp4-listen:53,reuseaddr,fork udp:127.0.0.1:5555,sourceport=55550,reuseaddr
```

Now I can make multiple queries.

Before 1st query:

```
# netstat -aunp|egrep -w '53|5555'
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*                           12715/nc.openbsd    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           12717/socat
```

After 1st:

```
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55550         127.0.0.1:5555          ESTABLISHED 12736/socat         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          127.0.0.1:55550         ESTABLISHED 12715/nc.openbsd    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           12717/socat
```

After 2nd query:

```
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55550         127.0.0.1:5555          ESTABLISHED 12750/socat         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5555          127.0.0.1:55550         ESTABLISHED 12715/nc.openbsd    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           12717/socat         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            127.0.0.1:53255         ESTABLISHED 12750/socat
```

Socat would suffer the same problem but with the `fork` option, it listens again, and it appears it detects the previous lost “connection”; I think that causes a delay.

You can get the old behaviour (works once) if you just remove the `,sourceport=55550,reuseaddr` part in the socat command.

Comment: using UDP-RECVFROM instead of UDP-LISTEN should improve socat behaviour (it won't become established)