# Tunnelling UDP Traffic Through OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, tunnel, udp

Referring to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/358248/389915) I'm trying to route UDP streaming through an available OpenVPN tunnel. On the VPN client machine, I've access to a UDP stream over an IP (udp://1.2.3.4:5555) which I want to listen to it on VPN server machine through that vpn tunnel. I tried different questions and couldn't find my answer. Here's the VPN connection status:

> *VPN Server which I want to get the UDP stream on*
>
> > tap0  **inet addr:100.64.100.1  Bcast:100.64.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0**

And

> *VPN Client which I have access to that UDP stream on*
>
> > tap0     **inet addr:100.64.100.2  Bcast:100.64.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0**

Any reference or help is appreciated,

Comment: Why are the two addresses routable? They should be private

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration does not look ok. On the one hand you are using a tap0 interface, which indicates the use of a bridged OpenVPN, which is perfect. But on the other hand, the interfaces have public, rouable addresses, while they should have private, non-routable addresses belonging to the LAN to which the client is trying to connect.

This being said, stream an UDP stream is simple, *vlc* can do it, see for instance [this very good guide](https://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marius, that vlc guide is providing information about starting an stream. But in my case, I do have access to an available UDP stream on my VPN client and want to send it to the VPN server through the tunnel and view it there.

Comment: By the way, the tunnel between both servers is already established. So I think the current step is to set routes for source and destination so when things are called on VPN server, they flow through the current bridged tunnel. Any clue?

Comment: The link is broken to videolan.org