# UDP over TCP, windows platforms

Tags: tunnel, ssh-tunnel, udp

I have read: [UDP traffic through SSH tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel#) a number of times, but I don't think it directly answers this question:

I am looking to forward UDP traffic (udp Port 8004): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Image_Generator_Interface
From a windows 10 computer (server in a private cloud) to windows 10 computer (client).

My prefered solution would be an existing program that I could run on both the client and the cloud computer.

The issue is that UDP traffic the private cloud is limited to RDP and TCP connections. UDP data is not forwarded.
Can I tunnel the UDP traffic over a TCP connection, and then have the data appear as local UDP packets on the client.

I am not sure if either of the below solutions will work, or if they are for a different problem.

- https://securesocketfunneling.github.io/ssf/#home
- https://github.com/BarbaTunnelCoder/BarbaTunnel/

Getting our I.T. department to approve a true VPN between the private cloud and client computers might take years :-(

Comment: A good answer for this can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566208/how-to-forward-udp-packets-over-tcp-udptunnel?rq=1