# How to port forward UDP though SSH

Tags: ssh, tcp, udp

I have a setup where I'm forwarding port 5000 to a remote server with `ssh -NR 5000:localhost:5000 root@server` This only forwards TCP packets through the SSH tunnel, Due to new software which is picky about using UDP, I need to forward UDP packets too.

I have done some googling to see if this is possible and it appears its not. Is there any way I can 'convert' the UDP packets to TCP so they flow through the tunnel and then back to UDP at the remote server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UDP traffic through SSH tunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel)