# Traffic ALL windows client traffic through ssh (udp included)

Tags: windows, ssh

i want to be able to traffic all windows device through ssh , i can connect using dynamic ports and transfer tcp no problem , but we need udp as well .
i have tried socat so far .
the reason im doing this is that in my country all internet is almost blocked and the only thing remaining is ssh connections .

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of guides for using SSH as a VPN. For UDP specifically, take a look at the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/53103/udp-traffic-through-ssh-tunnel

Comment: im going by the guides over there , but i get the "microserver socks protocol not supported yet" .

Comment: That is worth asking a new question for. It would involve what you're using as an SSH client and server, and information about how both ends are configured. Maybe some packet captures. As one of the comments mentions, it can be difficult to configure, since TCP streams are not guaranteed to preserve message boundaries, so a single UDP datagram may be split in parts, breaking any protocol.